# Выдает ошибку сколько бы не делал python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
import os
import datetime
import time
import vk_api

# Функция для загрузки видео в группу ВКонтакте
def upload_video_to_group(vk, group_id, video_path):
    upload_url = vk.video.save(group_id=group_id)['upload_url']
    video_file = {'video_file': open(video_path, 'rb')}
    response = vk.method('video.save', {'group_id': group_id}, files=video_file)
    video_id = response['video']['id']
    owner_id = response['video']['owner_id']
    return video_id, owner_id

# Функция для добавления видео в отложенные записи группы ВКонтакте
def add_video_to_delayed_posts(vk, group_id, video_id, owner_id, publish_date):
    vk.method('video.add', {'target_id': -group_id, 'video_id': video_id, 'owner_id': owner_id, 'publish_date': publish_date})

# Функция для получения времени публикации на следующий день в 8 часов по московскому времени
def get_publish_date():
    moscow_tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=3))
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now(tz=moscow_tz)
    next_day = current_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    publish_date = datetime.datetime.combine(next_day.date(), datetime.time(hour=8, minute=0), tzinfo=moscow_tz)
    return publish_date.timestamp()

group_id = 75627603  # ID вашей группы ВКонтакте
video_folder = r'C:\Users\karl\Downloads\work pub\Видео'  # Путь к папке с видео

# Авторизация ВКонтакте
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='token')
vk = vk_session.get_api()

# Загрузка и добавление видео в отложенные записи
for filename in os.listdir(video_folder):
    if filename.endswith('.mp4'):
        video_path = os.path.join(video_folder, filename)
        video_id, owner_id = upload_video_to_group(vk, group_id, video_path)
        publish_date = get_publish_date()
        add_video_to_delayed_posts(vk, group_id, video_id, owner_id, publish_date)
        print(f'Видео "{filename}" загружено и добавлено в отложенные записи на {datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(publish_date)}')'''

    time.sleep(60)  # Пауза 1 минута между загрузкой каждого видео
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: VkApiMethod.__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: В следующий раз будьте осторожнее при выкладывании кода, который содержит персональный токен, иначе другие могут получить доступ к вашей группе

Comment: [ask] - в следующий раз начни отсюда

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей в таких случаях стоит оставить тревогу модераторам, чтобы убрать персональнные данные

Comment: @Grundy понял! Буду иметь ввиду

Comment: @Grundy https://coub.com/view/1snzof

Comment: @andreymal, нужно :-)

Answer (score 0):

`vk.method` не задокументирован в документации.

Вам надо заменить его на

```py
vk.video.add(target_id = -group_id, video_id=video_id, owner_id=owner_id, =publish_date=publish_date)
```